# How to remove an item from Redis set using a property as determination?

Tags: redis, servicestack

When we remove items from a Redis Set using servicestack typed client

```
redisset = typedclient.Sets["setkey"];
redisset.remove(object1);
```

It usually will check every properties of object1, how do we define class of object1 which property to check for equality?

For example, object1 has those properties

```
session_key:"somekey"
session_name:"a name"
author:"Harry"
...
```

When we try to remove it from a set, we only want it to check to see if the session_key is matching and ignore other properties.

I thought I saw it once some where but I couldn't find it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complex types in Sets are blobbed as JSON. None of Redis Operations work on blobbed values which are opaque to Redis. You would need to go through each item in the Set on the client, i.e. deserialize it back into an object, check the session key then remove the matching entry.

The only option to do this on the server is to use a custom server-side lua script to parse the json into a Lua object and check the property that way.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But just to make sure, what I meant is when I try to remove a certain item from a set using typed client, set1.remove(item1) I assume that the remove method will match every properties of the item1 to the set member items and when it found a match it will remove it. What I'm asking is whether there is a way so that I can tell the remove method to only looking for a match of a certain property but not all of those

Comment: I also remembered seen it from somewhere that I can override some method called Equal-something when I define the class of the item

Comment: @shawhu You're confusing unrelated concepts here, every thing needs to be the same because Redis is comparing 2 opaque JSON strings for equality. This is not to be confused with overriding equality members in .NET classes which can only apply in .NET programs, i.e. not on the Redis server.

Comment: Thanks, got it! So what you really saying is that no matter what client, typed or not, it will still serilize the object to string and send it as a string value to the redis server to do SREM.